# I am trying to connect my Macbook Pro (Mac OS X - Version 10.7.4) to a Samsung SyncMaster S20B300 monitor

Tags: display, macbook-pro, mini-displayport

I am trying to connect my Macbook Pro (Mac OS X - Version 10.7.4) to a Samsung SyncMaster S20B300 monitor.

As soon as I connect the minidisplay port into the monitor, it turns it off (puts it in sleep mode - on/off button flashes).

Andy advise how to get this to work?

Comment: i have the same problem, have retrieved a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `System Preferences -> Displays`

From there try `Detect Displays` or `Arrangement` to get the monitor to work.

If this does not help, make sure the input on your external monitor is set to what ever type of connection you are using, i.e. VGA or DVI or HDMI. Oblivious check and make sure the connections are not loose too.